# Changing the value of a field in a map function of Stream

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to change the value of a field in a `Stream`. I am trying to change it in a `.map` but I got a compilation error

> Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

the stream:

```
user.getMenuAlertNotifications()
    .parallelStream()
    .filter(not -> not.getUser().getId()==userId &&
                   notificationList.getIds().contains(not.getId()))
    .map(not -> not.setRead(Boolean.TRUE) -> not)
    .forEach(not -> menuService.save(not));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You aren't going to transform the `Stream<MenuAlertNotification>` to a `Stream<Boolean>`, so don't use [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) which is supposed to be a **[non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference)**, [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness) operation:

```
.filter(...)
.forEach(not -> {
    not.setRead(Boolean.TRUE);
    menuService.save(not);
});
```

On a side note, `not` conveys a negative remark which some might find confusing or strange (I did). I would rename that lambda argument to `notification`, though you can find a shorter option.

---

By the way, the construction `not -> not.set Read(Boolean.TRUE) -> not` might be transformed into a perfectly valid expression:

```
.<Consumer<MenuAlertNotification>>map(not -> n -> n.setRead(Boolean.TRUE))
```

Comment: `peek` would work - don't know if it's a good idea either though. Not what it was intended for.

Answer (score 1):

```
.map(not -> {
    not.setRead(Boolean.TRUE);
    return not;
})
```

I think `peek` makes more sense in this case, since you are returning the same element though:

```
peek(not -> not.setRead(Boolean.TRUE))
```

You can probably also just use `true` instead of `Boolean.TRUE`.

Note that this might not be run for all of the elements in the stream (if it short circuits for example, but it will be for the non-filtered elements in the stream in the question since `forEach` is the terminal operation).

Also the `Function` passed to [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) should be [non-interfering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#NonInterference) and [stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness), so you should make sure the `setRead` method is both of those things.

Comment: Whilst this answer compiles, encouraging incorrect use of the API is not a great idea.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I don't believe this is an incorrect use of the API, could you tell me what about it is incorrect?

Comment: @BoristheSpider how is this incorrect? This is *not* a structural modification of the source of the stream

Comment: I guess it depends if they mean non-interfering should not update any fields of the object, but I take it as should not add or remove elements from the Collection that is the source of the stream

Comment: `map` is intended to transform one type into another. Running a side-effect and returning the same type is not the intent of the API.

Comment: @BoristheSpider its still not breaking the api either, I do not agree, at all. Streams are not intended for lots of things, still people (ab)use it. This is entirely valid, +1

Comment: @BoristheSpider `setRead` is not necessarily a side-effect, and I agree they probably intended the main use of `map` to be returning a different object but the spec doesn't require that, it just says: Returns a stream consisting of the results of applying the given function to the elements of this stream.

Comment: Okay, point taken - it's probably not incorrect. I still think it goes against the intent of the API and not the correct way to use `map`.